# if statement loops in timer

Tags: java

I have a break timer application. It uses a timer class to keep time and notify me via text message when my break is over. It all works, except it sends me a text message every second once the if statement becomes true. So I got about 60 messages in a minute and it will keep going while it is running. I have tried rewriting the if statement many different ways and it still does the same thing. I know that there is no such thing as if loops but that is what it is doing. the now variable is outside the timer loop, declared in the public class. I post most of the classes code below.

```
     private static long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
       public BreakTimer() {
        this.setText(when());
    }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     (some more code)            
        long currenttime = System.currentTimeMillis() - now;
        int breaknotify = 15 - SettingsIni.breaknotifytime();

                    if ((currenttime) /6000 == breaknotify){                                    
                            try {
                                TextMessage.main(null);
                            } catch (AddressException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }               
                    }       
        }
public void start() {
        BreakTimer.reset();
        timer.start();     
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        running = true;
        BreakTimer jtl = new BreakTimer();
        jtl.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the timer when the first text message is sent. The Timer class has a stop() method for this.

```
   if ((currenttime) /6000 == breaknotify){                                    
          try {
              TextMessage.main(null);
              //stop the timer here
           } catch (AddressException e) {
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without stopping the timer? I want to keep track of how much time I was over the break.

Comment: Of course. You can keep a boolean variable that is set to true when you send teh message. Only send the message if the boolean is false. This way you only send once. Alternatively, you can start a second timer to count the over time.

Comment: Ended up creating a different timer just for the textmessage so that I can stop it.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division, this will return true far more often than not.  I would recommend doing this:

```
if ( (currenttime)/ 6000.0 == breaknotify
```

Further you need to terminate the timer.

Comment: I have tried doing the divsion in the int but it's not making a difference. I also do not see difference in your recommendation from my code besides the 6000.0

Comment: @user1753429 you are doing integer division, my recommendation is to NOT do integer division.  Since with int division anything after the "." point is ignored.  Tacking on a `.0` to one of the parameters or casting as double will ensure that the values after the "." are not ignored and incorporated into the equation.

Comment: so you are saying it is treating 15.0, 15.1, 15.2 as if they were all the same in terms of triggering the if statement

Comment: @user1753429 yes.  At no point would it ever receive a value such as `15.0`, it would only receive 15.  Notice how you are only using longs and ints.

Comment: i changed it to 6000.0 also changed the int and long to double, but now it dosn't trigger.

Comment: @user1753429 Ok it doesn't trigger?  if you don't post the code there is no way to validate it one way or the other.  What happens when you walk through the debugger?

Comment: Why would it not work when I remove the division assuming there is nothing wrong with the math? Posting a working code probably isn't possible.

Comment: @user1753429 why is it not possible?  change names to protect the innocent

Comment: really just because it uses too many classes, the timer was the only relevant portion but you couldn't run it to test without the other classes.